# My webscraper stops reading data off the website after a few lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

was trying to webscrape off of nikes website for practice and save the data in a csv file. It works completely fine in regards to saving data into the file but however it only saves the first 24 shoes(name of shoe,price,colors etc) even though there are 50+ shoes on the page im trying to read. Note that initially the page displays fewer shoes but as we keep scrolling down it starts showing more shoes but even initially it displays a little over 24 shoes.
its my first scraper and my first post so im sorry if something is unclear but help is appreciated.
thanks

````
from urllib.request import urlopen


mylink = "https://www.nike.com/w/mens-soccer-shoes-1gdj0znik1zy7ok"
opened = urlopen(mylink)
read = opened.read()
opened.close()

page = soup(read, "html.parser")
containers = page.findAll("div", {"class":"product-card__info"})

file = open("nike.csv" , "w")
headers = "Name , Type, Colors, Price \n"
file.write(headers)


for container in containers:
    namecontainer = container.findAll("div", {"class": "product-card__title"})
    name = namecontainer[0].text

    typecontainer = container.findAll("div", {"class": "product-card__subtitle"})
    type = typecontainer[0].text

    colors = container.findAll("div", {"class": "product-card__count-wrapper"})
    no_of_colors =  colors[0].button.div.text

    pricecontainer = container.findAll("div", {"data-test": "product-price"})
    price = pricecontainer[0].text
    print("name: " + name)
    print("type: " + type)
    print("colors: " + no_of_colors )
    print("price : " + price + "\n")
    file.write(name.replace(",","|") + "," + type.replace(",","|") + "," + no_of_colors + "," + price + "\n)```
````

Comment: The problem is the way the website is set up. The div-elements of the shoes that are not visible before you scroll also aren't in the html document of the page.They appear after scrolling. So you would need to simulate the scroll before they can be read from the html document. Maybe look into [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/), this would allow you to scroll to the bottom of the page, before you search for the divs.

Answer (score 1):

The page loads new products as you scroll down the page using JavaScript. You can simulate it using `requests` module.

For example:

```
import re
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.nike.com/gb/w/mens-football-shoes-1gdj0znik1zy7ok'
page_url = 'https://api.nike.com/cic/browse/v1'

endpoint = '/product_feed/rollup_threads/v2?filter=marketplace(GB)&filter=language(en-GB)&filter=employeePrice(true)&filter=attributeIds({concept_id})&anchor={anchor}&consumerChannelId={channel_id}&count={count}'
data = {'queryid': 'products', 'endpoint': endpoint}

with requests.session() as s:
    soup = BeautifulSoup( s.get(url).text, 'html.parser' )

    concept_id = soup.select_one('meta[name="branch:deeplink:$deeplink_path"]')['content'].split('=')[-1]
    channel_id = re.search(r'"channelId":"(.*?)"', str(soup)).group(1)

    curr = 0
    while True:
        data['endpoint'] = endpoint.format(concept_id=concept_id, channel_id=channel_id, anchor=curr, count=50)
        json_data = s.get(page_url, params=data).json()

        # uncomment this to print all data:
        # print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4))

        # print some data to the screen:
        for i, o in enumerate(json_data['data']['products']['objects'], curr+1):
            print('{:<3} {:<60}{:<10}{}'.format(i, o['publishedContent']['properties']['title'], o['productInfo'][0]['merchPrice']['currentPrice'], o['productInfo'][0]['productContent']['colorDescription']))

        if i % 50:
            break

        curr += 50
```

Prints:

```
1   Nike Mercurial Superfly 7 Elite CR7 Safari FG               249.95    White/Black/Total Orange
2   Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Elite CR7 Safari FG                 239.95    White/Black/Total Orange
3   Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Elite FG                            219.95    Metallic Bomber Grey/Particle Grey/Laser Crimson/Black
4   Nike Mercurial Superfly 7 Elite FG                          229.95    Metallic Bomber Grey/Particle Grey/Laser Crimson/Black
5   Nike Phantom Vision 2 Elite Dynamic Fit FG                  229.95    Metallic Bomber Grey/Particle Grey/Laser Crimson/Black
6   Nike Phantom Venom Elite FG                                 219.95    Metallic Bomber Grey/Particle Grey/Laser Crimson/Black
7   Nike Tiempo Legend 8 Elite FG                               189.95    Metallic Bomber Grey/Particle Grey/Laser Crimson/Black
8   Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Elite Korea FG                      239.95    White/Black/Pink Beam/Red Orbit
9   Nike Mercurial Superfly 7 Elite Korea FG                    249.95    White/Black/Pink Beam/Red Orbit
10  Nike Mercurial Superfly 7 Club CR7 Safari MG                64.95     White/Black/Total Orange
11  Nike Phantom Vision Academy MG By You                       94.95     Multi-Colour/Multi-Colour
12  Nike Mercurial Superfly 7 Academy FG By You                 94.95     Multi-Colour/Multi-Colour
13  Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Academy FG By You                   84.95     Multi-Colour/Multi-Colour
14  Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Elite FG By You                     234.95    Multi-Colour/Multi-Colour
15  Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Club IC                             42.95     Black/Black
16  Nike Phantom Venom Elite AG-Pro                             219.95    Metallic Bomber Grey/Particle Grey/Laser Crimson/Black
17  Nike Phantom Vision 2 Academy Dynamic Fit TF                79.95     Metallic Bomber Grey/Particle Grey/Laser Crimson/Black
18  Nike Mercurial Superfly 7 Elite AG-PRO                      229.95    Metallic Bomber Grey/Particle Grey/Laser Crimson/Black
19  Nike Mercurial Superfly 7 Pro FG                            129.95    Metallic Bomber Grey/Particle Grey/Laser Crimson/Black
20  Nike Tiempo Legend 8 Academy MG                             64.95     Metallic Bomber Grey/Particle Grey/Laser Crimson/Black
21  Nike Phantom Vision 2 Pro Dynamic Fit FG                    129.95    Metallic Bomber Grey/Particle Grey/Laser Crimson/Black
22  Nike Tiempo Legend 8 Club MG                                42.95     Laser Crimson/White/Black
23  Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Academy MG                          69.95     Metallic Bomber Grey/Particle Grey/Laser Crimson/Black
24  Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Pro FG                              114.95    Metallic Bomber Grey/Particle Grey/Laser Crimson/Black
25  Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Academy TF                          69.95     Metallic Bomber Grey/Particle Grey/Laser Crimson/Black
26  Nike Mercurial Superfly 7 Academy MG                        79.95     Metallic Bomber Grey/Particle Grey/Laser Crimson/Black
27  Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Club Neymar Jr. MG                  47.95     White/Volt/Black/Racer Blue
28  Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Club MG                             42.95     Black/Black
29  Nike Phantom Vision 2 Academy Dynamic Fit MG                79.95     Metallic Bomber Grey/Particle Grey/Laser Crimson/Black
30  Nike Tiempo Legend 8 Pro FG                                 114.95    Metallic Bomber Grey/Particle Grey/Laser Crimson/Black
31  Nike Mercurial Superfly 7 Club MG                           59.95     Laser Crimson/Laser Crimson/Black
32  Nike PhantomVNM Club FG                                     47.95     Laser Crimson/Black/Metallic Silver
33  Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Elite AG-PRO                        219.95    Metallic Bomber Grey/Particle Grey/Laser Crimson/Black
34  Nike Phantom Vision 2 Elite Dynamic Fit AG-PRO              229.95    Metallic Bomber Grey/Particle Grey/Laser Crimson/Black
35  Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Club TF                             42.95     Black/Black
36  Nike Tiempo Legend 8 Academy TF                             64.95     Metallic Bomber Grey/Particle Grey/Laser Crimson/Black
37  Nike Mercurial Superfly 7 Academy AG                        79.95     Metallic Bomber Grey/Particle Grey/Laser Crimson/Black
38  Nike Mercurial Superfly 7 Elite TF                          154.95    Metallic Bomber Grey/Particle Grey/Laser Crimson/Black
39  Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Club Neymar Jr. TF                  47.95     White/Volt/Black/Racer Blue
40  Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Club Neymar Jr IC                   47.95     White/Volt/Black/Racer Blue
41  Nike Mercurial Superfly 7 Elite IC                          154.95    Metallic Bomber Grey/Particle Grey/Laser Crimson/Black
42  Nike Mercurial Superfly 7 Academy TF                        79.95     Metallic Bomber Grey/Particle Grey/Laser Crimson/Black
43  Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Academy IC                          69.95     Metallic Bomber Grey/Particle Grey/Laser Crimson/Black
44  Nike Mercurial Superfly 7 Academy IC                        79.95     Metallic Bomber Grey/Particle Grey/Laser Crimson/Black
45  Nike Tiempo Legend 8 Elite AG-PRO                           189.95    Metallic Bomber Grey/Particle Grey/Laser Crimson/Black
46  Nike Phantom Vision 2 Academy Dynamic Fit IC                79.95     Metallic Bomber Grey/Particle Grey/Laser Crimson/Black
47  Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Academy AG                          69.95     Metallic Bomber Grey/Particle Grey/Laser Crimson/Black
48  Nike Phantom Vision 2 Academy Dynamic Fit AG                79.95     Metallic Bomber Grey/Particle Grey/Laser Crimson/Black
49  Nike Tiempo Legend 8 Academy IC                             64.95     Metallic Bomber Grey/Particle Grey/Laser Crimson/Black
50  Nike Phantom Vision Elite FG By You                         244.95    Multi-Colour/Multi-Colour
51  Nike Mercurial Superfly 7 Elite FG By You                   244.95    Multi-Colour/Multi-Colour
52  Nike Phantom Vision 2 Elite Dynamic Fit FG                  147.47    Black/Black
53  Nike PhantomVNM Club TF                                     47.95     Black/Volt
54  Nike Mercurial Superfly 7 Club TF                           59.95     Black/Cool Grey/Metallic Cool Grey
55  Nike Tiempo Legend 8 Elite FG                               121.97    Black/Total Orange/White
56  Nike Phantom Vision 2 Academy Dynamic Fit TF                56.97     Black/Black
57  Nike Phantom Venom Elite AG-Pro                             140.97    Laser Crimson/Black/Metallic Silver
58  Nike Mercurial Superfly 7 Elite MDS AG-PRO                  159.97    Lemon Venom/Black
59  Nike Premier II Anti-Clog Traction SG-PRO                   73.47     Off Noir/Laser Crimson/Off Noir
60  Nike Premier II FG                                          63.97     Black/Volt/Electric Green/White
61  Nike Tiempo Legend 8 Elite AG-PRO                           121.97    Black/Black
62  Nike React Phantom Vision 2 Pro Dynamic Fit TF              67.47     Black/Black
63  Nike Premier 2 Sala IC                                      60.47     Black/Total Orange/White
64  Nike Mercurial Superfly 7 Elite SG-PRO Anti-Clog Traction   153.97    Black/Black
65  Nike Phantom Venom Pro FG                                   73.97     Black/Black
66  Nike Phantom Vision Elite Dynamic Fit AG-PRO                147.47    Dark Grey/Black/Bright Mango
67  Nike Phantom Vision 2 Academy Dynamic Fit SG-PRO Anti-Clog Traction60.47     Black/Black
68  Nike Lunar Gato II IC                                       56.97     Dark Smoke Grey/Black/Volt/White
69  Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Academy Neymar Jr. IC               64.47     White/Racer Blue/Volt/Black
70  Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Elite FG                            153.97    Black/Matte Silver/Metallic Cool Grey/Black
71  Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Pro Neymar Jr. FG                   87.47     White/Racer Blue/Volt/Black
72  Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Academy Neymar Jr. MG               64.47     White/Racer Blue/Volt/Black
73  Nike Mercurial Superfly 7 Academy MDS MG                    60.47     Lemon Venom/Black
74  Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Elite MDS AG-PRO                    153.97    Lemon Venom/Black
75  Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Elite MDS FG                        167.97    Lemon Venom/Black
76  Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Academy Neymar Jr AG                64.47     White/Racer Blue/Volt/Black
77  Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Academy MDS TF                      64.47     Lemon Venom/Black
78  Nike Mercurial Superfly 7 Academy MDS TF                    60.47     Lemon Venom/Black
79  Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Academy MDS MG                      64.47     Lemon Venom/Black
80  Nike Mercurial Superfly 7 Elite MDS FG                      174.97    Lemon Venom/Black
81  Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Academy MDS IC                      64.47     Lemon Venom/Black
82  Nike React Gato                                             73.97     Black/Total Orange/Dark Smoke Grey/White
83  Nike React Tiempo Legend 8 Pro IC                           67.47     Black/Laser Orange/Black
84  Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Academy Neymar Jr. TF               64.47     White/Racer Blue/Volt/Black
85  Nike Mercurial Superfly 7 Pro MDS AG-PRO                    97.97     Lemon Venom/Black
86  Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Elite Neymar Jr. FG                 167.97    White/Racer Blue/Volt/Black
87  Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Elite Neymar Jr. AG-PRO             167.97    White/Racer Blue/Volt/Black
88  Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Academy MDS AG                      64.47     Lemon Venom/Black
89  Nike Phantom Vision 2 Elite Dynamic Fit AG-PRO              147.47    Laser Crimson/Black/Metallic Silver
90  Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Pro IC                              67.47     Black/Black
91  Nike Tiempo Legend 8 Elite SG-PRO Anti-Clog Traction        127.97    Laser Crimson/White/Black
92  Nike Phantom Vision 2 Elite Dynamic Fit SG-PRO Anti-Clog Traction153.97    Laser Crimson/Black/Metallic Silver
93  Nike Phantom Venom Elite FG                                 140.97    Desert Sand/Black/Electric Green/Psychic Purple
94  Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Elite AG-PRO                        153.97    Black/Black
95  Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Academy TF                          60.47     Laser Crimson/Laser Crimson/Black
96  Nike Phantom Venom Academy IC                               60.47     Laser Crimson/Black/Metallic Silver
97  Nike Tiempo Legend 8 Elite FG                               121.97    Black/White/Black
98  Nike Tiempo Legend 8 Pro FG                                 73.97     Black/White/Black
99  Nike Phantom Vision Elite Dynamic Fit Anti-Clog SG-PRO      153.97    Dark Grey/Black/Bright Mango
100 Nike Tiempo Legend 8 Academy SG-PRO Anti-Clog Traction      60.47     Black/White/Black
101 Nike Phantom Vision Elite Dynamic Fit FG                    147.47    Dark Grey/Black/Bright Mango
102 Nike PhantomVNM Academy SG-Pro Anti-Clog Traction           64.47     Black/Black
103 Nike Phantom Venom Elite SG-Pro Anti-Clog Traction          147.47    Laser Crimson/Black/Metallic Silver
104 Nike Tiempo Legend 8 Elite FG                               132.97    Laser Crimson/White/Black
105 Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Elite SG-PRO Anti-Clog Traction     147.47    Black/Black
106 Nike Phantom Venom Academy AG                               60.47     Laser Crimson/Black/Metallic Silver
107 Nike Tiempo Legend 8 Pro FG                                 80.47     Laser Crimson/White/Black
108 Nike Phantom Venom Academy FG                               60.47     Laser Crimson/Black/Metallic Silver
109 Nike Phantom Venom Elite FG                                 153.97    Laser Crimson/Black/Metallic Silver
110 Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Elite MDS FG                        167.97    Blue Void/White/Black/Metallic Silver
111 Nike Mercurial Superfly 7 Academy SG-PRO Anti-Clog Traction 60.47     Laser Crimson/Laser Crimson/Black
112 Nike Mercurial Superfly 7 Elite SG-PRO Anti-Clog Traction   167.97    Blue Hero/Volt/Obsidian/White
113 Nike Tiempo Legend 8 Elite SG-PRO Anti-Clog Traction        127.97    Black/White/Black
114 Nike Phantom Venom Academy FG                               60.47     Black/Black
115 Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Academy SG-PRO Anti-Clog Traction   64.47     Laser Crimson/Laser Crimson/Black
116 Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Elite MDS AG-PRO                    167.97    Blue Void/White/Black/Metallic Silver
117 Nike Phantom Vision 2 Academy Dynamic Fit AG                55.97     Laser Crimson/Black/Metallic Silver
118 Nike Tiempo Legend 8 Academy MG                             60.47     Black/White/Black
119 Nike Phantom Vision 2 Pro Dynamic Fit FG                    90.97     Laser Crimson/Black/Metallic Silver
120 Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Academy SG-PRO Anti-Clog Traction   64.47     Blue Hero/Obsidian/White
121 Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Pro AG-PRO                          80.47     Black/Cool Grey/Metallic Cool Grey
122 Nike Phantom Vision Pro Dynamic Fit FG                      83.47     Dark Grey/Black/Bright Mango
123 Nike Phantom Vision 2 Pro Dynamic Fit AG-PRO                90.97     Laser Crimson/Black/Metallic Silver
124 Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Pro TF                              67.47     White/Black/Laser Crimson
125 Nike Premier II Anti-Clog Traction SG-PRO                   67.47     University Red/Laser Crimson/Black
126 Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Academy TF                          60.47     Blue Hero/Obsidian/White
127 Nike Tiempo Legend 8 Academy AG                             60.47     Laser Crimson/White/Black
128 Nike Phantom Vision 2 Academy Dynamic Fit IC                56.97     Black/Black
129 Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Pro MDS IC                          67.47     Blue Void/White/Black/Metallic Silver
130 Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Pro IC                              67.47     Laser Crimson/Laser Crimson/Black
131 Nike React Tiempo Legend 8 Pro IC                           67.47     Laser Crimson/White/Black
132 Nike Tiempo Legend 8 Pro AG-PRO                             80.47     Laser Crimson/White/Laser Crimson/Black
133 Nike Tiempo Legend 8 Academy IC                             60.47     Laser Crimson/White/Black
134 Nike Mercurial Superfly 7 Elite MDS SG-PRO Anti-Clog Traction166.47    Blue Void/White/Black/Barely Volt
135 Nike Tiempo Legend 8 Academy MG                             60.47     Laser Crimson/White/Black
136 Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Pro IC                              67.47     Blue Hero/Obsidian/White
137 Nike React Phantom Vision 2 Pro Dynamic Fit IC              73.47     Laser Crimson/Black/Metallic Silver
138 Nike Phantom Vision 2 Academy Dynamic Fit SG-PRO Anti-Clog Traction60.47     Laser Crimson/Black/Metallic Silver
139 Nike Tiempo Legend 8 Pro TF                                 67.47     Black/Black
140 Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Academy IC                          60.47     Blue Hero/Obsidian/White
141 Nike Tiempo Legend 8 Pro SG                                 57.97     Black/Black
142 Nike Premier II Anti-Clog Traction SG-PRO                   73.47     Black/Volt/White
143 Nike Phantom Venom Academy TF                               60.47     Laser Crimson/Black/Metallic Silver
144 Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Academy IC                          60.47     Laser Crimson/Laser Crimson/Black
145 Nike Phantom Vision 2 Club Dynamic Fit IC                   54.97     Laser Crimson/Black/Metallic Silver
146 Nike Tiempo Legend 8 Academy AG                             60.47     Black/White/Black
147 Nike Mercurial Superfly 7 Elite MDS AG-PRO                  159.97    Blue Void/White/Black/Metallic Silver
148 Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Elite SG-PRO Anti-Clog Traction     160.97    Black/Matte Silver/Metallic Cool Grey/Black
149 Nike Phantom Venom Pro AG-Pro                               80.47     Laser Crimson/Black/Black/Metallic Silver
150 Nike Tiempo Legend 8 Elite SG-PRO Anti-Clog Traction        127.97    Black/Blue Hero/Black
151 Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Pro Neymar Jr. AG-PRO               87.47     White/Racer Blue/Volt/Black
152 Nike Premier II FG                                          63.97     Obsidian/Black/Light Current Blue
153 Nike Phantom Vision Academy Dynamic Fit TF                  56.97     Volt/Volt/White
154 Nike PhantomVNM Academy SG-Pro Anti-Clog Traction           64.47     Bright Mango/Orange Pulse/Anthracite/White
155 Nike Phantom Venom Academy FG                               60.47     Bright Mango/Orange Pulse/Anthracite/White
156 Nike Phantom Venom Elite FG                                 153.97    Volt/Volt/Barely Volt/Obsidian
157 Nike Phantom Venom Academy TF                               60.47     Bright Mango/Orange Pulse/Anthracite/White
158 Nike Mercurial Superfly 7 Academy TF                        56.97     Blue Hero/Obsidian/White
159 Nike Phantom Venom Elite SG-Pro Anti-Clog Traction          147.47    Black/Volt/Black
160 Nike Mercurial Superfly 7 Pro AG-PRO                        83.47     Black/Cool Grey/Metallic Cool Grey
161 Nike Tiempo Legend 8 Elite FG                               132.97    Black/Blue Hero/Black
162 Nike Phantom Vision Academy Dynamic Fit MG                  56.97     Volt/Volt/White
163 Nike Tiempo Legend 8 Elite AG-PRO                           121.97    Black/Blue Hero/Black
164 Nike Superfly 6 Elite FG                                    147.47    Hyper Crimson/White/Metallic Silver/Black
165 Nike Phantom Vision Elite Dynamic Fit Anti-Clog SG-PRO      153.97    Volt/Barely Volt/White
166 Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Elite MDS SG-PRO Anti-Clog Traction 159.97    Blue Void/White/Black/Metallic Silver
167 Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Pro FG                              73.97     Black/Cool Grey/Metallic Cool Grey
168 Nike Mercurial Superfly 7 Academy SG-PRO Anti-Clog Traction 60.47     Blue Hero/Obsidian/White
169 Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Academy MG                          60.47     Blue Hero/Obsidian/White
170 Nike PhantomVSN Academy Dynamic Fit SG-Pro Anti-Clog Traction60.47     Volt/Volt/White
171 Nike Phantom Venom Pro FG                                   73.97     Volt/Volt/Obsidian
172 Nike PhantomVSN Academy Dynamic Fit SG-Pro Anti-Clog Traction60.47     Dark Grey/Black/Black/Bright Mango
173 Nike Mercurial Vapor 13 Academy MDS SG-PRO Anti-Clog Traction56.97     Blue Void/White/Black/Metallic Silver
174 Nike PhantomVNM Elite Tech Craft FG                         153.97    Black/Black/Black
175 Nike Phantom Venom Academy AG                               60.47     Bright Mango/Orange Pulse/Anthracite/White
176 Nike React Tiempo Legend 8 Pro IC                           67.47     Black/Blue Hero/Black
177 Nike Phantom Venom Academy IC                               62.97     Volt/Volt/Obsidian
178 Nike Tiempo Legend 8 Pro SG                                 73.97     Black/Blue Hero/Black
179 Nike Premier II Anti-Clog Traction SG-PRO                   67.47     Black/Black/Hyper Crimson
180 Nike Phantom Vision Academy Dynamic Fit IC                  56.97     Volt/Volt/White
181 Nike Phantom Venom Pro AG-Pro                               73.97     Volt/Volt/Obsidian
182 Nike Tiempo Legend 8 Academy SG-PRO Anti-Clog Traction      60.47     Black/Black
183 Nike Mercurial Superfly 7 Academy IC                        56.97     Blue Hero/Obsidian/White
184 Nike Zoom Phantom Venom Pro TF                              67.47     Volt/Volt/Obsidian
185 Nike Mercurial Superfly 6 Academy MG                        63.47     Black/Black/Light Crimson/Black
186 Nike Zoom Phantom Venom Pro IC                              67.47     Bright Mango/Orange Pulse/Anthracite/White
```

Comment: im not really familiar with js and i just got started with webscraping so i am gonna learn selenium next maybe that will help me. However i did scroll to the bottom before copying the url so i thought it would show me all the shoes

Comment: @NeyMuaaz11 `BeautifulSoup`/`requests` don't execute JavaScript. My example just simulates queries that normal page makes from the browser.